# PhoneGap (iOS) (xcode v.4.3.3) - Errors building project to app simulator

Tags: xcode, cordova

Hello stackoverflow members,

This is my first time using PhoneGap, and after creating a project "Hello World", and opening it with Xcode, I get these build errors when I try to run it in the simulator:

```
Unknown type name '_commandQueue'; did you mean 'CDVCommandQueue'?
Expected identifier or '('
Unknown receiver '_commandQueue'; did you mean 'CDVCommandQueue'?
No known class method for selector 'resetRequestId'
Unknown receiver '_commandQueue'; did you mean 'CDVCommandQueue'?
No known class method for selector 'fetchCommandsFromJs'
Unknown receiver '_commandQueue'; did you mean 'CDVCommandQueue'?
No known class method for selector 'dispose'
Property 'commandQueue' requires method 'commandQueue' to be defined - use @synthesize,      @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation
```

Does anyone here have an idea of how to fix these errors by any chance?

I am using Xcode v4.3.3 and the latest version of PhoneGap.

Thank you for your time,

Jonathan.

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

@synthesize commandQueue = _commandQueue;

before the __init method and rebuild.